Proof that the intersection of the inductive subsets of $a$ is independent of $a$
For brevity, I will write $\mathcal I(a)$ in place of "$a$ is an inductive set" from now on. I want to show that, for all $a$ and $b$, if $\mathcal I(a)\land\mathcal I(b)$, then
$$\bigcap\{e\subseteq a\mid\mathcal I(e)\}=\bigcap\{e\subseteq b\mid\mathcal I(e)\}$$
I don't really know how to approach this problem. Any help will be appreciated.
Note. $\mathcal I(a)\iff\varnothing\in a\land\forall x(x\in a\implies\bigcup\{x,\{x\}\})\in a$

@RobArthan of course, thank you. I corrected.

“I don't really know how to approach this problem.” Well, have you tried to understand what the common value for the $\bigcap {e ⊆ a | \mathcal{I}(e)}$ could be?

@JeanAbouSamra of course, it should be $\omega$. I'm trying to define $\omega$ this way though, so I don't really have an a priori notion of it.

@RobArthan no, I want $\bigcup{x,{x}}\in a$. My aim is to define the set of natural numbers ${\varnothing,{\varnothing},{\varnothing,{\varnothing}},\dots}$.

The key is to prove that the intersection of two inductive sets is inductive. Then both sides are equal to $\bigcap \{e\subseteq a\cap b: \mathcal{I}(e)\}.$
If $x\in \bigcap\{e\subseteq a\cap b: \mathcal I(e)\},$ and $e\subseteq a$ is inductive, then $e\cap b$ is an inductive subset of $a\cap b,$ so $x\in e\cap b,$ hence $x\in e.$ So $x\in \bigcap\{e\subseteq a: \mathcal I(e)\}.$ Conversely, if $x\in \bigcap\{e\subseteq a: \mathcal I(e)\}$ and $e\subseteq a\cap b$ is inductive, then obviously $e\subseteq a$, so $x\in \{e\subseteq a\cap b: \mathcal I(e)\}.$

I did prove that the intersection of an arbitrary number of inductive sets is inductive. I am not able to prove rigorously that both sides equal $\bigcap{e\subseteq a\cap b:\mathcal I(e)}$.

@Elvis If $e$ is an inductive subset of $a$ then $e\cap b$ is an inductive subset of $a\cap b.$
